# Sharing Facebook access_token with another users

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

Does anyone know if this is permitted?

I want to get the `access_token` from a user maybe sometime in the future use it to retrieve a `photo` without another interaction from the initial user. I would be using only his access_token that I saved.

Is this a bad practice or something? Should I not be doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad practice to store access token in dB and use it at a later stage without user interaction. But the normal token expires in 1-2 hours, you first have to exchange this token with the `long-lived token` (that expires in 60 days).

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
  grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
  client_id={app-id}&
  client_secret={app-secret}&
  fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

[More details](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#extending)

But, I don't understand your title: `Sharing Facebook access_token with another users`- what another users?

I think you didn't wrote the title correctly, but this answer is what you need. Let me know for any doubts.